# Django view: Convert unicode retrieved from db to string

Tags: python, django

In django view I retrieve data from a table in MySQL db using

```
 diag_patient = Diagnosis.objects.get(patient=myid)
 diag_val = diag_patient.diagnosis_option 
 print "diagnosis value=", diag_val
```

When I print `diag_val` I get `[u'One', u'Two']`
I want to convert it to a string equal to `One, Two`.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
 import ast
 str_diag_val =ast.literal_eval(diag_val)
 print "diag value=", str_diag_val[0], " ", str_diag_val[1]
```

And this converts string representation of list to a list.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question about Django, it's about lists and strings in Python.

It looks like `diag_val` is a list, not unicode. You can concatenate a list of strings with [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
", ".join(diag_value)
```

Comment: Using your proposed solution I get `[, u, ', O, n, e, ...` I want to get the string `One, Two`. So, it this a list?

Comment: In that case, it looks as if you are storing the string representation of a list `"[u'One', u'Two']"` in your database. That's a bad idea. It should be possible to parse the string, but I recommend that you find the place where you are adding the data to the database, and save it in a better format e.g. `'One, Two'`.

Comment: The data are gathered from `forms.MultipleChoiceField` and are stored automatically using `.save()` the view.py.

Comment: Storing the input from a `forms.MultipleChoiceField` in a `CharField` isn't a good idea, because the resulting string `"[u'One', u'Two']"` is hard to manipulate. I would concentrate on fixing this, instead of trying to parse the string. I don't have a ready answer to this for you, hope you manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What we want to do here is convert a list, `diag_val` to a string, say `str_diag_val`.
We can do this using the 'join' method.

```
 diag_patient = Diagnosis.objects.get(patient=myid)
 diag_val = diag_patient.diagnosis_option
 str_diag_val = ", ".join(str(s) for s in diag_val) //to typecast the elements of the list into string
 print "diagnosis value=", str_diag_val
```

Comment: Using your proposed solution I get [, u, ', O, n, e, ... I want to get the string One, Two. So, it this a list?

Comment: Good to know you found the solution.